# PHP login system help needed for deletion

Tags: php, authentication

Help with user deletion:

Hello I am creating a user creation system for a project of mine, I am still very new to PHP, my issue is getting the user from the MySQL database and then deleting it, I will show you my code below:

```
            <?php
            require_once("config/db.php");

            if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
                if  ($_SESSION['user_perm'] == 1) {

                    //Create Connection
                    $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
                    // Check connection
                    if ($db_connection->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $db_connection->connect_error);
                    } 

                    $sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
                    $result = $db_connection->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo $row["user_name"];
                            $user_name_delete = $row["user_name"];
                            $_SESSION['user_name_delete'] = $user_name_delete;
                                echo '<a href="deleteuser.php">Delete User</a><br>';
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    $db_connection->close(); ?>
```

On the deleteuser.php page my code is, note this was just a test:

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['user_name_delete'];
?>
```

My issue with this is grabbing the user who you selected to delete as at the moment it only outputs the last user grabbed from the database.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @David Hi David, I do know how to delete data from a database, the issue I am having is detecting the user I want to be deleted, as at the moment only the very last user will be deleted no matter which user you select to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value:

```
$_SESSION['user_name_delete']
```

Is going to contain only the last user in your data.  Because you keep overwriting it in your loop:

```
$_SESSION['user_name_delete'] = $user_name_delete;
```

The short answer is... Don't use session state for this.  (Really, you shouldn't use session state for much of anything unless you absolutely have to.)  The identity of the user to be deleted should be included in the request to delete the user.  In this case, you can add it to the link.  Something like this:

```
echo '<a href="deleteuser.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Delete User</a><br>';
```

(Or whatever you use to identify the user in the data row.)

Then in `deleteuser.php` you can get that value from:

```
$_GET['id']
```

Validate the inputs, validate that the user is authorized to perform the delete, and then use that value in the `WHERE` clause of your `DELETE` query.

Comment: @bobbyjane: It looks like someone disagrees, since this answer has a down-vote :)  But I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Get the users id and insert it into a delete query.
`$id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`
`$sql = "delete from users where id = " . $id;` and then run the query to delete the user from the database.

Comment: Please don't recommend SQL injection vulnerabilities.  There are already enough of those in the world.